# javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${not empty short}]

Tags: jsp, el

I have a simple spring web app. The ELs do not get compiled and I get a javax.el.ELException for any and all EL expressions.

Here's what I've tried:

1. jstl 1.2 is on the app's classpath.
2. I've tried adding <%@ pageisELIgnored="false" %> to top of the page.

Doesn't work for me.

Code and log:

1. Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.dx.shortner")
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

2. jsp file:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="tf" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<tf:jsinclude></tf:jsinclude>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Shortener - Shorten URLs</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                <c:if test="${not empty short}">
                    <div class="h3">${short}</div>
                </c:if>
                <form action="shorten">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="longURL">Your URL Here:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="longURL" />
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Shorten!</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

3. webapp dir structure

```
webapps/shortner
├── css
├── js
│   └── lib
├── META-INF
│   ├── MANIFEST.MF
│   └── war-tracker
├── views
│   └── index.jsp
└── WEB-INF
    ├── classes
    │   ├── com
    │   │   └── dx
    │   │       └── shortner
    │   │           ├── config
    │   │           │   ├── SpringConfig.class
    │   │           │   └── WebAppInitializer.class
    │   │           ├── domain
    │   │           │   └── Shortened.class
    │   │           ├── service
    │   │           │   └── ShortnerService.class
    │   │           └── ShortnerController.class
    │   ├── log4j.properties
    ├── lib
    │   ├── commons-lang3-3.9.jar
    │   ├── commons-text-1.7.jar
    │   ├── jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
    │   ├── jackson-core-2.9.8.jar
    │   ├── jackson-databind-2.9.8.jar
    │   ├── javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar
    │   ├── javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
    │   ├── jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar
    │   ├── jstl-1.2.jar
    │   ├── log4j-1.2.17.jar
    │   ├── slf4j-api-1.8.0-alpha2.jar
    │   ├── slf4j-log4j12-1.8.0-alpha2.jar
    │   ├── slf4j-simple-1.7.26.jar
    │   ├── spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    │   ├── spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    │   ├── spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    │   ├── spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    │   ├── spring-expression-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    │   ├── spring-jcl-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    │   ├── spring-web-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    │   └── spring-webmvc-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar
    └── tags
        └── jsinclude.tag
```

4. error log:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /views/index.jsp (line: [16], column: [4]) [${not empty short}] contains invalid expression(s): [javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${not empty short}]]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:41)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:291)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:97)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1423)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1232)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:880)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1545)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2444)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:471)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1854)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:221)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
.
.
.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: shot in the dark: given that `short` is the name of a primitive type in Java, have you tried not using a variable name `short`?

Comment: that's right! it worked! saved from losing more hair. Thanks!

Comment: *"The ELs do not get compiled and I get a javax.el.ELException for any and all EL expressions."* So, this was actually not true? Why did you start your question with an apparently unconfirmed assumption?